# Understanding 3D rotation

Tags: vectors, 3d, coordinate-systems, rotations

I’m trying to understand how 3D vector rotation work, and I will understand it best if I have a chance
to observe the actual process of how the correct calculations are supposed to be.

With default value (you can change the values if you want! I just want to see the process):

- Rotating vector = **v** = (-2,-2,-2)

  Rotational vector = **n** = (3,3,3)

  Pivot point = P = (1,1,1)

  Angle of rotation = θ = 60 degrees

Please do the step by step calculation, and please provide illustrated diagram for each step (I’ve already made the diagram
in this link below, you just need to edit it to fit in each step).

Link: https://www.mathcha.io/editor/1Y2E0fYzIDmI9oHm4VXkyt91QYO7sVr5Y6mh59wLLV
[image]

**Formulas for the calculation:**

Rodigues’ Rotation formula:

- **v’** = (1-cos(θ))[(**v·n^**)**n^**]+cos(θ)**v**+sin(θ)**n^×v** (I’m interested in
  seeing how this formula work, so I don’t prefer using 3D rotation matrix at
  the moment)

Rotation around pivot point formula (2D, I haven‘t seen any confirmed 3D version of the formula, please write the 3D one if you know the correct formula):

- v.x’ = [(v.x-P.x)*cos(θ)-(v.y-P.y)*sin(θ)]+P.x
- v.y’ = [(v.x-P.x)*sin(θ)+(v.y-P.y)*cos(θ)]+P.y

My other questions regarding the same subject:

1. Can P (the pivot point) be considered as a vector? If it is, is it correct to say ‘’Rotation around a vector formula’’ instead of  ‘’Rotation around pivot point formula’’?
2. Is there exist the 3D version of the ‘’Rotation around pivot point formula’’ above? Can you please provide it if there are any?
3. Is Rodigues’ Rotation formula supposed to control the ‘’direction’’ of the rotation and ‘’Rotation around pivot point formula’’ supposed to control the ‘’position’’ of
   the rotation? Can you please provide proof if possible? I don’t have any better way to word these mathematical terms, if you do, please word them for me.

Thank you. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Also, I really need to observe the process to understand, but if you don’t do it, you can also answer the 3 questions above! Thank you!*

Comment: In 3D rotation you have fixed rotation axis, and not any pivot point.

Comment: Somebody has asked to close this well written and illustrated question. In this case, almost all questions should be closed...

Comment: Consider using matrices, it gives another wiewpoint.

Comment: @Somos 
Thank you for the information. Is it the same as ''Rotation around arbitrary axis''? Is this the same concept that you are talking about? If it is, then I've already been using Rodrigues' Rotation Formula to solve the problem, if it's not, can you please link me to the article where I can read more about ''fixed rotation axis''? Thank you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607640/rotating-a-vector-in-3d-space#:~:text=Rotation%20around%20Arbitrary,to%20this%20problem.

Comment: @JeanMarie If you are the moderator, thank you for not closing my post. Can you please tell me the pros of using matrices? From my newbie eyes, they are just different approaches to solve the same problem. I've searched through multiple sites and most uses formulas instead of matrices. Also, information regarding matrices and their derivations are so scarce that I've decided to study and use formulas instead (I'm self taught so I don't have a teacher to ask about these things).

Comment: @JeanMarie
I want to add something. What I've been seeing is that matrices and formulas are just **different looking tools** that are made to do the same task. In this link (I know you may already seen this), the matrix literally is just a different way to express the rotation formula. What do you think about it?: 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#:~:text=This%20rotates%20column,after%20rotation%20are

Comment: @Somos Is this the same subject that you are mentioning?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721544/circular-rotation-around-an-arbitrary-axis#:~:text=To%20perform%20a,to%20the%20origin.